# What does the result of this integral mean or represent

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

If we have a wire shaped like C parabola $y=1-x^2$, the length of the wire should be $\int _C dl$ where dl is a infinitesimal element of the length what will $\int_C F(x,y) dl$ generally  mean or represent ?

Answer (score 2):

Integrals can have many varied interpretations.

If the wire you described has density $F(x,y) \frac{\textrm{grams}}{\textrm{cm}}$ and the unit of the coordinate grid is centimeters, then $\int_C F(x,y)\textrm{ d}l$ would represent the mass of the wire.

If you create a "variable height ribbon" whose base is $C$ and whose height is at point $(x,y) \in C$ is $F(x,y)$, then the same integral will represent the area of this ribbon.

Depending on the context, this integral could have a million interpretations.  I will refer you to my answer [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/24888/117) for a more in depth perspective on how one operation (integration) can have many different interpretations.